# Build Zip archive, special cases

Tags: zip

How can I create a zip in a linux distro and
- keep only the relative path to a folder
- put some files in a separate folder inside the zip

I need to do this in a bash script so if i just use the absolute path the entire path will be inside the zip.

Example

```
/home/user/folder/1.txt
/home/user/folder/2.txt
```

Output Need It :

```
test.zip
folder/1.txt
folder/secondfolder/2.txt
```

Comment: How does the output relate to the example?

Comment: Might this be better suited to ServerFault? It seems more like a sysadmin question than a programming question to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
( cd /var/www ; zip -r - test1 ) > output.zip
```

Comment: this is correct regardless of duplicate +1

Answer (score 0):

Does `find . ! -name "*.zip" -type f -print | zip test -@` do what you want?

Comment: `zip` is capable of recursing a path on its own.

Comment: I updated the question. This is not what I need.

Comment: @user, *I updated the question* -- adding "need it" is hardly an update! (Also, please come up with a better title?)

Comment: @Ignacio and Charles, so maybe `zip -r -x *.zip` would achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the directory structure you want and then zip it and then remove it?

```
cd ~/
mkdir backup1
cp /var/www/test/* backup1/
zip -r output.zip ~/backup1
rm -r backup1
```

Comment: Because I'm used to command line flexibility and I thought I'm missing something. Good tip though.

Comment: man zip doesn't seem to allow you to create directories.  If you want to do in one line; just cp /var/www/test/* backup1/ && zip -rm output.zip backup1/  (m for move the files) part is to not have to have feature-bloat; there's no real reason to let zip create files/dirs that don't exist, when you can do it perfectly fine with other commands.

Answer (score 0):

> $ ln -s /var/www/test backup1
>   $ zip -r backup1 -j backup1/*

Acceptable?

Comment: You are junking the directories and create a new sim link in the process.. I don't think it's optimal. Thanks anyways.