# Linux Zip - Make an archive using absolute paths

Tags: linux, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Build Zip archive, special cases](https://superuser.com/questions/216181/build-zip-archive-special-cases)

So I'm using bash to create an archive.
I have to supply a full path to the zip cli.

Something like this : zip -r output.zip /var/www/test1

The problem is that the archive will preserve the entire directory structure starting with /var /www /test1

I just need an archive with the folder test1 and it's subdirectories.