# Linux Zip - How to create a folder

Tags: linux, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Build Zip archive, special cases](https://superuser.com/questions/216181/build-zip-archive-special-cases)

I'm using zip to archive different files.
I need to create a directory in the zip file where to place some of them. Is that possible ?

The syntax I got so far is
       zip output.zip -r /var/www/test

Inside the zip I want a folder called backup1 and in there the files from /test.